# Skip to certain time in HTML5 video via a button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, html5-video

I am trying to jump to a point in a video when a button is clicked.

So I have my buttons which look like this:

```
   <!-- Chapter 1 = Skip to 20s -->
  <button id="ch1">Chapter 1</button>
   <!-- Chapter 2 = Skip to 100s -->
  <button id="ch2">Chapter 2</button>
```

Not sure what todo for the JS but this is what I have done so far:

```
  var vid = $("#video")[0];
  $("#ch1").click(skipTime(100));

  function skipTime(time) {
     vid.play();
     vid.pause();
     vid.currentTime = time;
     vid.play();
  };
```

Doesn't work after trying heaps of different combinations, have looked around and can't find anything that works. So I'm stumped, any suggestions of how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$("#ch1").click(skipTime(100));
```

To this, (*also, you should declare `skipTime` first, and only then assign it*):

```
$("#ch1").click(function(){
    skipTime(100);
});
```

When you use `skipTime(100)` it runs your function and return some value or *undefined* if nothing was returned from `skipTime`... and because that, the `click`-handler does not have a function to run on every click.

When you wrap it with `function(){ ... }` the `click`-handler will run the function on every click.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, worked great!
Also thanks for fully explaining why it works!

Comment: @sparcut. Glad to help :)